# kfd kfd: STONEY not supported in kfd

Tags: linux, debugging, archlinux

I been getting this error on my manjaro linux machine, here is some more info:

```
- Journal begins at Mon 2021-03-08 18:37:49 EET, ends at Tue 2021-03-09 16:21:19 EET. --
Mar 09 11:02:26 manjaro kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0xcfbb6000-0xcfbb9fff]
Mar 09 11:02:29 manjaro kernel: kfd kfd: STONEY  not supported in kfd
Mar 09 11:02:32 manjaro systemd-backlight[1332]: Failed to get backlight or LED device 'backlight:acpi_video0': No such device
Mar 09 11:02:32 manjaro systemd[1]: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0.
 Subject: A start job for unit systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service has failed
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
 
 A start job for unit systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service has finished with a failure.
 
 The job identifier is 1354 and the job result is failed.
Mar 09 11:02:32 manjaro systemd-backlight[1333]: Failed to get backlight or LED device 'backlight:acpi_video1': No such device
Mar 09 11:02:32 manjaro systemd[1]: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video1.
 Subject: A start job for unit systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1.service has failed
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
 
 A start job for unit systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1.service has finished with a failure.
 
 The job identifier is 1360 and the job result is failed.
```

I don't know if the `kfd` error it's happening because of the first error.
I would like to know what it actually means, where is it coming from, and how can I fix it?
And maybe a word on the `systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1.service` error.

The setup i have:

- Cpu:
  AMD A9-9420 RADEON R5, 5 COMPUTE CORES 2C+3G, 2586 MHz
- GPU:
  ATI Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics]
- 4GB RAM, 250GB SSD
- OS: Linux manjaro 5.9.16-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Dec 21 22:00:46 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux